# Border around each cell in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a simple function that will add borders around every cell in a certain range. Using the wonderful recording this generates a ton of code which is quite useless. The code below will display a 'table' of data, around each cell in this range I would like to add a border. Online I haven't been able to find a simple or clear answer for this.

All help is much appreciated!

```
Set DT = Sheets("DATA")
endRow = DT.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
result = 3

For I = 2 To endRow
    If DT.Cells(I, 6).Value = Range("B1").Value Then
        Range("A" & result) = DT.Cells(I, 6).Value
        Range("B" & result) = DT.Cells(I, 1).Value
        Range("C" & result) = DT.Cells(I, 24).Value
        Range("D" & result) = DT.Cells(I, 37).Value
        Range("E" & result) = DT.Cells(I, 3).Value
        Range("F" & result) = DT.Cells(I, 15).Value
        Range("G" & result) = DT.Cells(I, 12).Value
        Range("H" & result) = DT.Cells(I, 40).Value
        Range("I" & result) = DT.Cells(I, 23).Value
        result = result + 1
    End If
Next I
```

Comment: I edited my title seen as though it confused people.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You only need a single line of code to set the border around every cell in the range:

`Range("A1:F20").Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous`

It's also easy to apply multiple effects to the border around each cell.

For example:

```
Sub RedOutlineCells()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:F20")

    With rng.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = vbRed
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 12):

The following can be called with any range as parameter:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetRangeBorder(poRng As Range)
    If Not poRng Is Nothing Then
        poRng.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        poRng.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        poRng.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        poRng.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        poRng.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        poRng.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        poRng.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        poRng.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End If
End Sub
```

Examples:

```
Call SetRangeBorder(Range("C11"))
Call SetRangeBorder(Range("A" & result))
Call SetRangeBorder(DT.Cells(I, 6))
Call SetRangeBorder(Range("A3:I" & endRow))
```

Answer (score 11):

I have a set of 15 subroutines I add to every Coded Excel Workbook I create and this is one of them.  The following routine clears the area and creates a border.

**Sample Call:**

```
Call BoxIt(Range("A1:z25"))
```

**Subroutine:**

```
Sub BoxIt(aRng As Range)
On Error Resume Next

    With aRng

        'Clear existing
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

        'Apply new borders
        .BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThick, 0
        With .Borders(xlInsideVertical)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        With .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Great Template.

Comment: Thanks^^ Bold outline with Standard Dividing Lines.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way

```
Sub testborder()

    Dim rRng As Range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("B2:D5")

    'Clear existing
    rRng.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone

    'Apply new borders
    rRng.BorderAround xlContinuous
    rRng.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    rRng.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For adding borders try this, for example:

```
Range("C11").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Range("A15:D15").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
```

Hope that syntax is correct because I've done this in C#.

Comment: Doesn't really help, this will work on a range, but not per cell.

Comment: and, what exactly is this: Range("C11").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
or this: Range("A15:A15").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous

Comment: Idk that's what you've created nothing provided in my initial code.

Answer (score 1):

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1).Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = Excel.XlDataBarBorderType.xlDataBarBorderSolid
xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1).Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = Excel.XlDataBarBorderType.xlDataBarBorderSolid
xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1).Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = Excel.XlDataBarBorderType.xlDataBarBorderSolid
xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1).Borders(Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = Excel.XlDataBarBorderType.xlDataBarBorderSolid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also include this task within another macro, without opening a new one:

I don't put Sub and end Sub, because the macro contains much longer code, as per picture below

```
With Sheets("1_PL").Range("EF1631:JJ1897")
    With .Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Color = vbBlack
    .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End With
```

[part of a larger sub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Hke.jpg) (not shown as picture because it's a big picture)

Answer (score 0):

You can add border to any range in a very dynamic way by using the `AddBorder` and `GetCurrentRegionStartingGivenCell` function in Xatocode as follows:

```
' First you may define a worksheet level named range in starting cell and name it as rngData
Sub BorderExample()

    Dim rngData         As Range ' Range to sort

    Set rngData = GetCurrentRegionStartingGivenCell(shtData.Range("rngData"))

    Call AddBorder(rngData, EdgeLeft)
    Call AddBorder(rngData, EdgeTop)
    Call AddBorder(rngData, EdgeRight)
    Call AddBorder(rngData, EdgeBottom)
    Call AddBorder(rngData, InsideVertical)
    Call AddBorder(rngData, InsideHorizontal)
    Call AddBorder(rngData, DiagonalUp)
    Call AddBorder(rngData, DiagonalDown)
    Call ClearBorder(rngData)
    Call AddBorder(rngData, Box)
    Call AddBorder(rngData, AllBorder)
    Call AddBorder(rngData, AllBorder, xlDot) ' Linestyle
    Call AddBorder(rngData, AllBorder, , xlMedium) ' Thickness
    Call AddBorder(rngData, AllBorder, , , vbRed) ' Color
End Sub
```

You can read the complete article [here](https://xatocode.com/article/1004/excel-vba-easiest-way-to-add-border-to-a-range)