# Button to add column?

Tags: vba, excel

In excel 2013 I was hoping if someone can make a code for adding 1 blank column to a spreadsheet based on the user input after they click this button that is an activex control. The column will end based on how many rows there are in my table, meaning if there are 10 rows I should not see a column on line 11 of the spreadsheet.

I keep getting an error saying application defined or object error after I put in the column I want to add, I even tried both caps an lowercase and the same error comes up.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim x As String
x = InputBox("Enter a column that you want to add: ", "What column?")
If x = "" Then Exit Sub

ColumnNum = x
Columns(ColumnNum & ":" & ColumnNum).Insert shift:=xlShiftRight
Columns(ColumnNum - 1 & ":" & ColumnNum - 1).Copy Range("A1" & ColumnNum)
Columns(ColumnNum & ":" & ColumnNum).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [ask], and include the code in the question (not a screenshot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you started:

```
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim ColumnNum%
    x = InputBox("Enter a column that you want to add: ", "What column?")
    If x = "" Then Exit Sub
    ColumnNum = x
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(ColumnNum).Insert shift:=xlRight

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(ColumnNum - 1).Copy

    'THe line above doesnt make any sense whatsoever. 
     'Im not going to try and trouble shoot it but it seems like you dont understand how to
     ' properly scuplt things. Youll notice i changed how you strucutred the .copy part. 
     'THe part that doesnt make sense to me is the Range section. 

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(ColumnNum).ClearContents
```

There were a few things wrong with your code.

1. You need to put Option Explicit at the top of your code. You didnt declare your variables.
2. you inpout box needs to be declared as variant
3. When i played around with this its clear you didnt fully reference what columns in what sheets need to be inserted. Notice my "ThisWorkbook....."
4. Your if statement is structured incorrectly as well.

I suggest you spend some time reading up on the basics some more :)

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by reference what columns in what sheets? In terms of code? since I was planning on making this button universal meaning it doesn't matter the table size it will always make new columns until the table row ends, I feel like if putting in specific sheets and columns in the code will not make it universal? Since if those changes I have to change the code as weLL?

Comment: @Deathkamp yea that's fine but you still need to fully qualify what you're wanting to change. With out specifying in some way what exactly needs to be changed the compiler wont know the difference between sheet1 in book1 from sheet2 in book2 if that makes sense.

Comment: Also I get a type mismatch when i run the code? from   ColumnNum = x

Comment: Make sure your x is declared as variant at the top

Comment: yup  Dim x As Variant    and I even put option exlicit on top in the general tab and still same error?

Comment: this is code: http://imgur.com/a/dzsmE          I get an error on the private sub commandbutton2 of variable being undefined and then the **shift:=xlShiftRight** is highlighted

Comment: shift right isnt a built in function. I changed to xlRight. see edited posted

Comment: Ok it works but it does not generate the lines or boxes around the cells so that you are aware that its an extension of the table? Any Ideas? here is what I mean: http://imgur.com/a/GtvKb  notice the I column there are no lines??

Comment: Doug you there?

Comment: If you want to learn how to extend the lines, then you'll need to post in another question. HOwever you can easily google "add lines to excel sheet vba"

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121425/border-around-each-cell-in-a-range

Comment: The issue with the range is that the user defines it, so I cant hard-code the range to add lines to a specific cell range? Like in the link you showed me, and google only shows how to do rows and the same hard-coding the range?

Comment: ok I am getting really confused now. So tell me if I am wrong, in order to get the column the user inputs to have lines, I need to first pass the user's input to the UsedRange, then I need to call the range function and have its paramter be UsedRange? If I am right may I get an example of where to start?

Comment: Doug? HELP Please. Ive spent all day trying to figure this out and I cannot. Even made a new post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154245/button-generates-the-columns-from-user-input-but-not-the-cell-lines

Comment: i created a room for us to take this offline. i will be here but be patient b/c im at work

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130706/dzcoats