# Button Generates the columns from user input but not the cell lines?

Tags: excel, vba

I implemented a button that ask the user where to add a column, and the button takes the user input(A-Z) and generates the column until the end of the table **NOT SPREADSHEET**. The column ends based on how many rows there are in my table, meaning if there are 10 rows, after the user clicks the button an inputs where they want the column to be(They input a letter of the column A-Z), I should not see a column box on line 11 of the spreadsheet.

Now I've managed to do this my issue is below:

My issue is the cells the button generate does not include the lines or boxes around the cells so that you are aware that its an extension of the table?

here is what I mean: [Picture of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRoRm.jpg)

notice the i column there are no lines around the cells?

Here is code, I think I am missing a copy function after the line 
shift:=xlRight, but I don't know how to implement it?

I don't want to use macros because since the tables rows and column change due to the user's input I will have to constantly hard-code the range into the macro which i dont want.
Trust me I tried it an its annoying.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim x As Variant
Dim ColumnNum

x = InputBox("Enter a column that you want to add: ", "What column?")
If x = "" Then Exit Sub
ColumnNum = x

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(ColumnNum).Insert shift:=xlRight


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(ColumnNum).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim colIndex As Variant

    colIndex = Application.InputBox("Enter a column that you want to add: ", "What column?", , , , , , 2) '<--| force a text
    If colIndex = "" Then Exit Sub
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(colIndex) '<--| reference column you want to insert
        .Insert shift:=xlRight '<--| insert a new column , then the referenced one shifts one column to the right of the inserted one 
        .Offset(, -2).Copy '<--| copy the column two columns to the left of the referenced one (i.e. one column left of the new one)
        .Offset(, -1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats '<--| paste formats to the new column 
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @DeathKamp (alias "cloud"), if my answer solved _this_ post then please mark answer as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @Deathkamp, to accept an answer you have to _click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in_ (as you can see in [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))