# Button to add columns deletes previous column?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I made a button in excel 2013 that adds a new column to my table based on a user input. Now the button generates the column, however when I go to print preview somehow  the line that separates the column it copied from gets deleted. Here is what I mean:
![Print preview of the spreadsheet after new column generates][1]

Notice the training and warranty columns has no line separator, when the new column gets generated?

Also the new generated column, the first cell is not orange and is missing a line at the top. I am out of ideas and cant use macros because the table's rows and column changes, meaning the range changes.

here is code

```
      Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()
      Dim colIndex As Variant

     colIndex = Application.InputBox("Enter a column that you want to add: ",     "What column?", , , , , , 2)               '< force a text'
     If colIndex = "" Then Exit Sub
     With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(colIndex)                            'reference column you want to insert
    .Insert shift:=xlRight                                                      '<insert a new column , then the referenced one shifts one column to the right of the inserted one'
    .Offset(, -3).Copy                                                          '< copy the column two columns to the left of the referenced one (i.e. one column left of the new one)'
    .Offset(, -1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats                                    '< paste formats to the new column'
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
     End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi DeathKamp; are you user "cloud" of [this question about inserting cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154245/button-generates-the-columns-from-user-input-but-not-the-cell-lines/41159049#41159049) ?

Comment: yes and thanks for the help last time.

Comment: you are welcome. it'd be nice of you to give feedback and (possibly) close questions. and why are you changing names?

Comment: I am not sure how close it, and I was logged into this gmail so when I signed into stack it automatically used this gmail.

Comment: Inserting columns (or rows or cells) doesn't reliably copy the (intended) format of the surrounding cells, at least in my experience. So to ensure you get the intended format of the column, you'll need to modify the `Border` of the cells to make sure of it.

Comment: When you say modify the borders of the cells, do you mean manually through the format cells option or through VBA code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a column or row or cells to an existing range, I've learned that Excel doesn't reliably format that new range in the way I expect. For me, it's easier to explicitly format the newly added range so I know what I'm getting. In your case, you're looking for borders so your existing VBA code can do it...

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim newCol As Range
    Set newCol = ActiveSheet.Range("S1:S100")
    With newCol.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting the same result from my OP lol, I don't think it did anything.

Comment: Your OP works for me (I didn't try it before posting my answer). So here's my guess now... your column that is (-3) from your inserted column does not have the left border drawn. Look at the cell format settings manually and see. It looks correct because the adjacent column has its right side border turned on.

Comment: Hey peter is it possible if the button can copy the color as well, since when it generates the new column its just blank empty boxes? Notice the I column? [This is what I mean](http://imgur.com/a/Fd6cs)

Comment: Did you try `.Offset(,-1).ColorIndex = .Offset(,-3).ColorIndex`?

Comment: That line of code you posted only works if the entire column is the same color, but my patter is one row gray one row white an that repeats until end of table. With that code that you posted I am getting the object does not support this property?

Comment: Your OP with the `xlPasteFormats` should work. How about using that first and then setting the line style after the paste formats?

Comment: the Xl paste does work but the cell colors come out blank. here is picture : [here]http://imgur.com/a/m04dt                                                                    notice the I column is generated but no colors? I tried the                                         .Offset(,-1).ColorIndex = .Offset(,-3).ColorIndex    but wont work?

Comment: setting the line after the xl paste still has no colors in column?

Comment: Peter it works, its just that once the column is generated you have to put text in the boxes for everything get the colors.